# Losing first number in my array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, loops, object

finished this array to remove all duplicate inputs and print the frequency of each number, but it is dropping the lowest number inputted and its frequency! Also how would I turn this to be a vertical array instead of horizontal?
Can anyone help?
Here is the code currently

**ArraySort** Class

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArraySort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the numbers for your array.");
    int[][] d = new int [50][2];
    int[] a = new int [50];
    int[] b = new int [50];
    int[] c = new int [50];
    for(int index = 0; index < 50; index++)
    {
        a[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    ArraySort object = new ArraySort();
    object.sort(a);
    object.duplicate(a, b);
    object.frequency(a, c);



    for(int index = 0; index < 50; index++)
    {
        d[index][0] = b[index];
    }
    for(int x = 0 ; x < 50; x++)
    {
        d[x][1] = c[x];
    }
    for(int column = 0; column < 2; column++)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row < 50; row++)
        {
            System.out.print(d[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public int[] sort(int [] a)
{
    int temp = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < 49; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 49; y++)
        {
            if(a[y] < a[y+1])
            {

                temp = a[y];
                a[y] = a[y+1];
                a[y+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
public int[] duplicate(int [] a, int[] b)
{
    int y = 0;
    for(int x = 1; x < 50; x++)
    {
        if(a[x-1] != a[x])
        {
            b[y] = a[x-1];
            y++;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
public int[] frequency(int [] a, int [] c)
{
    int y = 1;
    int z = 0;
    for(int x = 1; x < 50; x++)
    {
        if(a[x-1] == a[x])
        {
            y++;
        }
        if(a[x-1]!= a[x])
        {
            c[z] = y;
            z++;
            y = 1;
        }   
    }
    return c;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This fix to `duplicate` might give you a hint how to fix `frequency`:

```
public int[] duplicate(int [] a, int[] b)
{
    int y = 1;
    b[0] = a[0];
    for(int x = 1; x < 50; x++)
    {
        if(a[x-1] != a[x])
        {
            b[y] = a[x];
            y++;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

To print your data as a vertical column, not two horizontal rows, interchange your row and column loops for printing.  That is, instead of this:

```
for(int column = 0; column < 2; column++)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < 50; row++)
```

switch them to this:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 50; row++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < 2; column++)
```

Comment: Even with this fix, the lowest number is still not being outputted or the frequency of the lowest number.

Comment: Are you _certain_ that the lowest number isn't being output by your print loop?  You still have to fix the code that computes the _frequencies_, but at least the duplicate finder should be correct.

Comment: Neither is being printed the lowest inputted number or the frequency. How would I fix the frequency loop? I dont see anything wrong with it

Comment: @Conrad : What would happen if all 50 elements were distinct?  Your loop can only write 49 distinct frequencies because it iterates 49 times, and only writes frequencies from within the loop.  To be correct, it has to handle either the first or last frequency explicitly, much like the change I suggested above.  BTW, I edited my post to show how to print the values vertically.

Comment: Appreciate it. Im really new to this to fix it to being 50 distinct elements would I have to change the less than to 50? Or what would I have to change? Sorry for the directness Ive been working since early this morning and this project is due in like 3 hours and Im freaking out. My professor doesnt speak much english and isnt very helpful so to StackOverflow I go!

Comment: For the frequencies:  The logic you have outputs the currently accumulated frequency whenever the new bin differs from the previous bin.  That's fine.  But, for the last frequency, there's no next bin to compare it to, so that last frequency never gets written out.  So, after the loop, you just need one additional step to write out the last frequency you accumulated.

Comment: so would that look something like c[z] + 1?

Comment: @Conrad : I'm pretty sure you just need `c[z] = y;` right before `return c;`.